# Exception "The Neo Server running is of unknown type." after updating to SDN 3.4.1

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I've somewhat successfully updated our SDN from 3.2 to 3.4.1.RELEASE.
Everything works, except for an exception that tells me `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Neo Server running is of unknown type. Valid types are Community, Advanced, and Enterprise.`.

After some googling this might have to do with [the (deprecated) way](http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2014/11/21/neo4j-browser-with-embedded.html) I'm enabling the web interface on the embedded neo4j instance.

Is this indeed the case? If so, is there a proper way to enable the web interface on an embedded neo4j instance?

Edit: On Supamiu's request: `"neo4j_version" : "2.2.5"`.

Comment: Using your web interface, can you get your neo4j version and add it to your question body please?

Comment: I suppose you are using maven, adding your pom.xml (and maybe the complete pom.xml) can be a good idea too, to see which dependencies you are using. Also, giving your neo4j starting code could be great (the one where you start the graphDatabaseService). I'll delete my comments once your question is edited, they are useless once it's done :)

Comment: Yeah, we're using maven, but I don't think the problem lies in the dependencies. If I use `return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("foo.db")` as graphDatabaseService, there's no problem. I enable the webinterface according to the link in my original post, which seems to lead to the exception.

Answer (score 2):

As "cmorgner" stated in [Github](https://github.com/structr/structr/issues/381#issuecomment-129556079) :

> We have not yet found a solution for the issue because the startup
>   process for an embedded Neo4j browser has changed / been deprecated.

So, this message is, in fact, only a warning and they seems to have no functionnal impact.

The class raising this Exception is [VersionAndEditionService](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.3/community/server/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/rest/management/VersionAndEditionService.java#L75).

The problem seems to come from the deprecated method you are using. So there is no fix for that, since it's deprecated.

Comment: Hi Supamiu, thanks for your answer. I was already leaning towards this being an issue with the deprecated API (see OP). Do you know if there is an undeprecated way to setup the webinterface for embedded Neo4j?

Comment: Yes you knew it was deprecated, but you did not know that it was the cause of your exception. Sadly I don't know the "new way" to setup a web interface. I think you should ask to neo4j's team using contact form on their website. Every tutorial I found is using this deprecated way too.

Answer (score 0):

Deprecation is a cop out without a valid alternative.

The detection before the exception is thrown is rather basic. It looks for a string in the class name. Extending the WrappingNeoServer and giving it a name that matches your Neo edition satisfies the check and suppresses the exception.

```
public class WrappingCommunityNeoServer extends WrappingNeoServer {
public WrappingCommunityNeoServer(GraphDatabaseAPI db) {
    super(db);
}

public WrappingCommunityNeoServer(GraphDatabaseAPI db, Configurator configurator) {
    super(db, configurator);
}

public WrappingCommunityNeoServer(GraphDatabaseAPI db, ConfigurationBuilder configurator) {
    super(db, configurator);
}
```

}